# Why is my C# MVC4 Session Wrapper Service not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, wrapper

I am trying to implement a wrapper for my session (Loose coupling so it is easy to make changes later) but I am having problems, either the storing into the session is failing, or the retrieval but I do not know which.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look at my code and tell me if there is anything obviously wrong, or a better way of doing what I am trying to do. I basically want to display different things to different types of user, but when I try to access the user in the ViewContext it is null.

Any links to tutorials or examples would be gratefully accepted.

Here is my code:

- User and WEB_USER_LEVEL have a one to many relationship
- I have used Entity Framework to create models from my existing database
- I am currently in the early stages of the project and the User is not coming from the database yet (as the structure will change) so I am creating a new User and populating it before using CurrentUserService.Login(user). i have tried pulling a user out of the data base and logging that user in but it still does not work.

**ICurrentUserService.cs** (in Infrastructure folder)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyProject.Infrastructure
{
    public interface ICurrentUserService
    {
        User CurrentUser { get; }
        void SetCurrentUser(WEB_USER user);
        void SetAdminStatus(bool type);
        bool GetAdminStatus { get; }
        void SetManagerStatus(bool type);
        bool GetManagerStatus { get; }
        void Login(User user);
        void Logout();
        int? TryGetCurrentUserId();
    }
}
```

**CurrentUserService.cs** (in Infrastructure folder)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MyProject.Controllers;
using MyProject.Infrastructure.Filters;

namespace MyProject.Infrastructure
{    

    public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
    {        
        public const string CurrentUserKey = "CurrentUser";
        public const string CurrentUserIdKey = "CurrentUserId";
        public const string IsAdminKey = "IsAdmin";
        public const string IsManagerKey = "IsManager";

        private readonly IDb _db;

        public CurrentUserService() : this(new Db()) { }

        public CurrentUserService(IDb db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public User CurrentUser
        {
            get
            {
                return (User)HttpContext.Current.Items[CurrentUserKey];
            }
        }

        public void SetCurrentUser(User user)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items[CurrentUserKey] = user;
        }

        public void SetAdminStatus(bool type)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[IsAdminKey] = type;
        }

        public bool GetAdminStatus
        {
            get { return (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session[IsAdminKey]; }
        }

        public void SetManagerStatus(bool type)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[IsManagerKey] = type;
        }

        public bool GetManagerStatus
        {
            get { return (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session[IsManagerKey]; }
        }            

        public void Login(User user)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[CurrentUserIdKey] = user.ID;
            HttpContext.Current.Items[CurrentUserKey] = user;
            SetManagerStatus(user.WEB_USER_LEVEL.IsManager);
            SetAdminStatus(user.WEB_USER_LEVEL.RefID == 1 ? true : false);
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items[CurrentUserKey] = null;
            HttpContext.Current.Session[CurrentUserIdKey] = null;
            SetManagerStatus(false);
            SetAdminStatus(false);
        }

        public int? TryGetCurrentUserId()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[CurrentUserIdKey] as int?;
        }
    }
}
```

**Extensions.cs** (in Infrastructure folder)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Infrastructure
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static User CurrentUser(this ViewContext view)
        {
            return (User)view.HttpContext.Items[CurrentUserService.CurrentUserKey];
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyProject.Infrastructure;
using MyProject.Infrastructure.Filters;
using MyProject.ViewModels;
using MyProject.Models;
using System.Data.Objects;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{    

    public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        readonly IDb _db;
        readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
        readonly IErrorReporter _errorReporter;

        public HomeController() : this(new Db(), new CurrentUserService(), new ErrorReporter()) { }

        public HomeController(IDb db, ICurrentUserService currentUserService, IErrorReporter errorReporter)
        {
            _db = db;
            _currentUserService = currentUserService;
            _errorReporter = errorReporter;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
        {
            // Create new user and populate
            _currentUserService.Login(user);
            return RedirectToAction("Home");
        }

        public ActionResult Home()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Trying to access in ViewContext in _Layout.cshtml when the Home view is loaded**

```
@using MyProject.Infrastructure

@if (ViewContext.CurrentUser() != null && ViewContext.CurrentUser().WEB_USER_LEVEL.IsManager) 
{
    @RenderPage("~/Views/Shared/_Menu.cshtml")
}
```

But ViewContext.CurrentUser() is always null.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an extension method on top of ViewContext, I would suggest that you create a ViewModel for your view and pass into it the data that your view needs.  Remember, any external data that a view needs should be fed into it through a ViewModel.  This makes for a clean one to one relationship that's easy to follow.

Comment: I have used view models to pass data to views before, but only when the data is specific to the view. For login data I would have to pass it to every view so every ViewModel would have to have the user stored in it. Is that a good way to do it?

Comment: Are you just trying to store your user information somewhere so it can be accessed throughout the app?  If so, you may want to look into the built-in features of Asp.Net related to membership (look at IPrincipal specifically too).  If you use the built-in stuff then you'll have the built-in "User" object available to you everywhere.  Sorry in case I'm not understanding your question.